# Problems when use GeoPandas for Itersection between two Lines?

Tags: python, geopandas

How to a get the points of intersection between two geodataframe with different Z?
In dataframe I Have just the name of line(index) and Geometry LineString Z.

I try this code but, always the intersections give the same Z value

I have two geodataframe df_cross and df_lines

```
def load_xyz(file_path, file_name, spatial_reference, sep=';', header=0):
df = pd.read_csv(file_path+'\\'+file_name, header=header, sep=sep,
                 names=['Line','X','Y','Z'])

spatial_reference = {'init': 'epsg:4326'}

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df.values,
                       crs=spatial_reference,
                       geometry=[Point(xyz) for xyz in zip(df['X'], df['Y'], df['Z'])],
                       columns=['Line','X','Y','Z'])

gdf = gdf.groupby(['Line'])['geometry'].apply(lambda x: LineString(x.tolist()))

return gpd.GeoDataFrame(gdf)


spatial_reference = {'init': 'epsg:32724'}

file_path = r'C:\Users\VN\Desktop'
file_name = r'xyz.csv'
df_lines = load_xyz(file_path, file_name, spatial_reference)

file_path = r'C:\Users\VN\Desktop'
file_name = r'xyz_cross.csv'
df_cross = load_xyz(file_path, file_name, spatial_reference)

for i in range(len(df_lines)):
    for j in range(len(df_cross)):
        if(df_lines.iloc[i]['geometry'].intersects(df_cross.iloc[j]['geometry'])):

            df_lines.iloc[i].geometry.intersection(df_cross.iloc[j].geometry).z

            df_cross.iloc[j].geometry.intersection(df_lines.iloc[i].geometry).z
```

Does anyone know the way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you cannot use Shapely (and GeoPandas) for 3D intersections (GeoPandas use Shapely for the geometries). Shapely ignores the z coordinates for geometric analysis ([Shapely manual: Geometric Objects](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#geometric-objects))

> A third z coordinate value may be used when constructing instances, but has no effect on the geometric analysis. All operations are performed in the x-y plane.

In the example below there is no intersection between the 3D red and blue lines, but one intersection between the 2D lines (dashed) in the xy plane (without z values).

[image]

With the [geometry module of Sympy](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/geometry/index.html) (true 3D geometry)

```
from sympy import *
L1 = Line3D(Point3D(213782,103540,150),Point3D(215128,103984,50)) # red line
L2 = Line3D(Point3D(214448,105316,210),Point3D(214920,103068,150)) # blue line
print L1.intersection(L2)
[]
```

but with Shapely

```
L1 = LineString([Point(213782,103540,150),Point(215128,103984,50)])
L2 = LineString([Point(214448,105316,210),Point(214920,103068,150)])
print L1.intersection(L2)
POINT Z (214753.6033746928 103860.499181548 124.4838065189337)
```

With the 2D lines in the xy plane

[image]

```
With shapely

L1 = LineString([Point(213782,103540),Point(215128,103984)])
L2 = LineString([Point(214448,105316),Point(214920,103068)])
print L1.intersection(L2)
POINT (214753.6033746928 103860.499181548)
```

And with sympy

```
L1 = Line(Point(213782,103540),Point(215128,103984))
L2 = Line(Point(214448,105316),Point(214920,103068))
print L1.intersection(L2)
[Point(43425540892/202211, 21001735400/202211)]
```

Answer (score 0):

With this solution I have the same results.

[image]

[image]

The XY of intersection are OK. But I need the Z value of two lines to the intersection point profile. In the picture I found for XY(2,1), Z1(3) and Z2(4).

The two lines don't have the same Z value for each point and the code give me always the same Z, independent of the order in the intersection function.

OBS: I need to found the interp values, because the point will probably not exist.

Regards.